# Efficiently distribute large number of events over a 1-year time span

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to efficiently and evenly distribute events over a year. For each year I have about 10^6 events. Each event should be assigned a date. Below I posted my approach which is quite slow. Do you see a way of speeding this up?

```
for year in range(start_year, end_year + 1):
    for evt in range(events_this_year):
        event_date = (datetime.datetime.strptime(str(year) + "-01-01", "%Y-%m-%d") + datetime.timedelta(days=365 * evt / events_this_year)).strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You transition back and forth from `datetime` to `str`, that's the heavy part.

First of all, you can create the year datetime once in the outer loop and not everytime inside, this will already improves performance by ~3.5x (on my machine).

keeping the results as datetime values instead of strings (if that's OK for you) give a 110x(!!) performance boost:

```py
import datetime
from timeit import timeit

start_year = 2010
end_year = 2020
events_this_year = 10 ** 5


def using_strptime():
    result = []
    for year in range(start_year, end_year + 1):
        for evt in range(events_this_year):
            event_date = (datetime.datetime.strptime(str(year) + "-01-01", "%Y-%m-%d") + datetime.timedelta(
                days=365 * evt / events_this_year)).strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
            result.append(event_date)
    return result


def using_delta():
    result = []
    sec_per_event = datetime.timedelta(seconds=365 * 24 * 60 * 60 // events_this_year)
    for year in range(start_year, end_year + 1):
        year_dt = datetime.datetime(year=year, month=1, day=1)
        cur_dt = year_dt
        for evt in range(events_this_year):
            cur_dt += sec_per_event
            result.append(cur_dt.strftime("%Y-%m-%d"))
    return result


def using_delta_nostring():
    result = []
    sec_per_event = datetime.timedelta(seconds=365 * 24 * 60 * 60 // events_this_year)
    for year in range(start_year, end_year + 1):
        year_dt = datetime.datetime(year=year, month=1, day=1)
        cur_dt = year_dt
        for evt in range(events_this_year):
            cur_dt += sec_per_event
            result.append(cur_dt) # no strftime
    return result


t1 = timeit('using_strptime()', globals=globals(), number=1)
t2 = timeit('using_delta()', globals=globals(), number=1)
t3 = timeit('using_delta_nostring()', globals=globals(), number=1)

print(t1)
print(t2)
print(t3)
print("Ratios:")
print(t1 / t2)
print(t1 / t3)
```

Output on my machine:

```
22.7066284
6.213773400000001
0.20198889999999992
Ratios:
3.654241463005393
112.4152287576199
```

Comment: unfortunately I need the date string. But your second function is already an improvement by a factor of 5 on my machine. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to ever create dates by strptime.

Compute the delta between elements and create a list of events based on the enumeration of your `events_this_year` times the position in this range:

```
import datetime
start_year = 2021
end_year = 2021

events_this_year = 10**6

# using this to compute the available time handles leap years
day_first = datetime.datetime(start_year,1,1,0,0,0,0)
day_last  = datetime.datetime(start_year,12,31,23,59,59,999)

# delta time between events if spaced equally is 
# whole available time divided by number of events
ticks_per_event = (day_last - day_first) / events_this_year

# enumerate range of events and use index (i) to multiply the delta 
# and add that to the 1st day
events = [(day_first + ticks_per_event * i, f"Event: {e}") 
          for i,e in enumerate(range(events_this_year))]

print(events[:5], "...", events[-5:], sep="\n")
```

Output:

```
[(datetime.datetime(2021, 1, 1, 0, 0), 'Event: 0'), 
 (datetime.datetime(2021, 1, 1, 0, 0, 31, 535999), 'Event: 1'), 
 (datetime.datetime(2021, 1, 1, 0, 1, 3, 71998), 'Event: 2'), 
 (datetime.datetime(2021, 1, 1, 0, 1, 34, 607997), 'Event: 3'), 
 (datetime.datetime(2021, 1, 1, 0, 2, 6, 143996), 'Event: 4'), 
 (datetime.datetime(2021, 1, 1, 0, 2, 37, 679995), 'Event: 5')]
...
[(datetime.datetime(2021, 12, 31, 23, 57, 21, 320005), 'Event: 999995'), 
 (datetime.datetime(2021, 12, 31, 23, 57, 52, 856004), 'Event: 999996'), 
 (datetime.datetime(2021, 12, 31, 23, 58, 24, 392003), 'Event: 999997'), 
 (datetime.datetime(2021, 12, 31, 23, 58, 55, 928002), 'Event: 999998'), 
 (datetime.datetime(2021, 12, 31, 23, 59, 27, 464001), 'Event: 999999')]
```

Just collecting the dates (you can `zip()` them back together them with your eventlist) for

```
from timeit  import timeit

k ="""
e = []
for year in range(start_year, end_year + 1):
    for evt in range(events_this_year):
        e.append( (datetime.datetime.strptime(str(year) + "-01-01", "%Y-%m-%d") + datetime.timedelta(days=365 * evt / events_this_year)).strftime("%Y-%m-%d"))
"""
print(timeit(k, number=2, globals=globals()))

k = '[day_first + ticks_per_event*i for i,e in enumerate(range(events_this_year))]'
print(timeit(k, number=2, globals=globals()))
```

takes

```
100.682846539  # yours
  1.786883751  # mine
```